# MS-Access filter control on subform via command button

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to activate this filter control in Access on a continuous subform via a command button control rather than using the filter button on the ribbon?

[image]

I'm aiming to disable the Access ribbon in the final application and quite like the features in this control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DoCmd.GoToControl "CurrentJobStatus"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
```

You may need to tweak the name of your field (I just took a guess based on what I saw in your jpg), but that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can use a command button that use run a macro to filter the form. the macro command is called `setfilter`  and in the 
`Where Condition =` you put something like `=[MIS team adding job] Like “*WhatEverYouAreFilteringby*”`